# Picking up changes from CouchDB in C#

Tags: c#, couchdb, dotnet-httpclient

I would like to pick up a specific document from _changes in couchDB.

Here is my query line, where FEED should be "continuous" and HEARTBEAT = "5000"

`"?filter=_doc_ids&feed="+FEED+ "&include_docs=true&heartbeat="+HEARTBEAT;`

I dont want to request the DB all the time to get the document, but for the DB to push the changes using the above parameters.

This means my c# code needs to keep a connection open for CouchDB to push the changes. This is being executed in its own thread.

I can get data using feed=longpoll, but the c# code just hangs when using continuous.

I'm thinking it has something to do with that im looking at it as an async to produce a .Result, but it should be a stream, so ive tried to do it using streams, but that just turned into a clusterf***. I spent too much time, and could not get it to work. It just stopped executing but not breaking with an exception, so i could not bughunt it.

Therefor i returned to this method, hoping it is possible with a little help :) It works for longpoll, but not for continuous.

```
internal void Listen (ref JobList jobList)
{
   HttpResponseMessage result = null;
   try
   {
       while (true)
       {
        result = _httpClient.SendAsync(_requestMessage).Result;
        var stringResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImportJobsResponse>(stringResult.Result);
        // Transfer the read objects to the jobList
        if (null != resultObject)
        {
            foreach (ImportJob job in resultObject.results[0].doc.ImportJobs)
            {
                jobList.addJob(job);
            }
         } 
      }
   } catch (JsonSerializationException jex)
   {
     // handle error, and write to log.
   } catch (Exception ex) // Needs to find out what errors can come here when using httpclient
   {
     // handle error, and write log.
   }
}
```

Can anybody help :) ty in advance.

Comment: Any answer will pivot off this link - so to avoid the appearance of plagiarism: https://danielwertheim.se/using-c-and-httpclient-to-consume-continuously-streamed-results/

Comment: TY for your answer. Ive looked into it, and i still cannot get it to work. Ive literally copied the example just to eliminate any noise from my own code, but it just wont work. It seems like there is something wrong with continuous.